# Google Cloud TTS engine ignoring break SSML tags on large chunks of text

Tags: php, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech, ssml

I'm trying to generate audio from a big paragraph, but Google is ignoring the  SSML tags.

The tags are respected if I trim the text to around three lines, but more than that makes them invisible.

```php
$body = [
  'input' => [
    'ssml' => '<speak><p>Client Acquisition Engine Funnel For Creative Professionals</p><break time="3000ms"/><p>Most creative professionals I know are great at what they do, they have happy customers and deliver a high standard of work. Most however aren\'t very adept at acquiring new clients and have fallen into the habit of relying too much on referrals.</p><break time="3000ms"/><p>I\'ll be honest here, I used to do that as well.</p><break time="3000ms"/><p>For a long time, I just thought: "Well, if keep turning out good work I\'ll keep getting referrals"?</p><break time="3000ms"/><p>Turns out, that\'s not the case at all. Relying on referrals is a highly risky \'strategy\' and is not recommended (I wrote about it here).</p><break time="3000ms"/><p>Deep down somewhere in your conscious you already know this and so every now and then you throw some money into Facebook & Google Ads and after burning through a fair amount cash and bearing little fruit, decide its not for you and carry on.</p><break time="3000ms"/><p>Also, relying on the 20% of your clients who bring in 80% of your revenue (those 1 or 2 hero long term clients who\'ve helped sustain your freelance business for years) is also a highly risky situation to be in. You wake in the middle of the night, every now and then, in a cold sweat.. they\'ve left you!</p><break time="3000ms"/><p>Phew! It was only a dream...</p><break time="3000ms"/><p>I was exactly like that, but then I started to develop and systemise my sales & marketing processes. So that would be able to build a predictable lead flow, attracting more ideal prospects, delivering value, pre-qualifying leads, inviting those with highest engagement to book time on my calendar, all the while automating 80% of that process.</p><break time="3000ms"/><p>The key is to understand your own sales process, breaking each of the stages down into steps and look to automating as much of the repetitive tasks as you can. Doing so will result in being able to attract and manage more leads, filter out the ideal customers, which in turn gives you me more time, money and freedom.</p><break time="3000ms"/><p>Sounds complicated, and if you don\'t have a clear pathway, it can quickly end up turning into a rabbit hole.</p><break time="3000ms"/><p>But you can stop faffing about and get on the right track by downloading the Client Acquisition Engine Funnel Map & Toolkit today.</p><break time="3000ms"/></speak>',
  ],
  'voice' => ['language_code' => 'en-US', 'name' => 'en-US-Wavenet-D'],
  'audioConfig' => ['audio_encoding' => 'MP3'],
];

$result = json_decode($client->post('https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/v1beta1/text:synthesize?key=[REDACTED]', $body)->getBody());

file_put_contents('test.mp3', base64_decode($result['audioContent']));
```

The request goes through successfully, but the break tags are missing. This is not only reproducible via code, but also on their public playground on the service website.

Answer (score 1):

I hit the same. I learned that if the SSML tags have any kind of error, they are all ignored, without any kind of error handling. Really unhelp of google to not provide feedback, or documentation explaining that this happens, but that's Google for you. My solution:

- Escape the input text for not allowed characters (&, ", ', <, >). A quick regex replace should do the tric.
- Ensure the " marks in the ssml tags are escaped using a \ character

e.g. this won't work:

```
<speak>The man said "hi". <break time="2s" /> I smiled.</speak>
```

But this should:

```
<speak>The man said &quot;hi&quot;. <break time=\"2s\" /> I smiled.</speak>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please open an [Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers),if you believe it is a bug so the Text-to-Speech Systems Engineers can fix the issue with the SSML tags that you're experiencing.